# One Button to update GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update all rows of a GridView one time by clicking one button:
aspx:

```
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxRoles" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceAllRoles"
    AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleID"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBoxRoles_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceRolePermissions" runat="server"
    TypeName="RolePermission" SelectMethod="GetRolePermissionByRoleID" 
    UpdateMethod="UpdateRolePermission">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListBoxRoles" Name="RoleID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListBoxRoles" Name="RoleID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewRolePermission" SkinID="GridViewSecurity" runat="server" style="width: 100%;"
    HeaderStyle-Height="50" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceRolePermissions">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="PermissionName" SortExpression="PermissionName" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxRead" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Read") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxUpdate" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Update") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonUpdateRolePermissions" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonUpdateRolePermissions_Click" />
```

I want to update all rows of the gridview once the ButtonUpdateRolePermissions clicked.
I tried:

```
    protected void ButtonupdateRolePermissions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow RolePermission in this.GridViewRolePermission.Rows)
        {
            this.ObjectDataSourceRolePermissions.Update();
        }
    }
```

but the update method not take Update and Read fields into consideration.

Comment: put the event method what your doing in it?

Comment: What you mean by "does the this.GridViewRolePermission.Rows is having all the rows?"

Comment: I mean is in your foreach loop condition : foreach(GridViewRow RolePermission in this.GridViewRolePermission.Rows) "Does this.GridViewRolePermission.Rows holding all the rows?"

Comment: what may prevent  it from holding all rows?

Comment: I am asking if it is getting all rows

Comment: yes  by walkthrough debug process it getting all rows